# Sidebar visibility in {WordPress template Hyerarchy, Newspaper Theme, TagDiv Composer}

Tags: theme-customizer

I have to admit that I often find Wordpress not so intuitive but let me explain what I mean in this specific case:

The right sidebar is not whowed on the homepage? Why? How can it be?

[image]

But ok.. let me investigate..
[image]

Does this means that PageBuilder delete the Widgetized Side Areas?

And this is what happens if I try to add the Widget Sidebar (which makes no sense to me.. a sidebar shouldn't be related to the whole page?)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The right sidebar is not whowed on the homepage? Why? How can it be?

The theme author has opted not to include it in that template. It's that simple.

> Does this means that PageBuilder delete the Widgetized Side Areas?

Possibly. Although the theme might be responsible for this. You would need to ask the developers of each.

> And this is what happens if I try to add the Widget Sidebar (which makes no sense to me.. a sidebar shouldn't be related to the whole page?)

This appears to be a feature of your page builder, and something you should ask them about.

Your issue here is ultimately how your *3rd-party* theme and page builder have decided to handle sidebars. If the way they have change the default behaviour is confusing to you, all I can suggest is that you ask them for help. Since this is not standard WordPress behaviour, the broader community is unlikely to be much help.